# Mutability of a class after conforming to protocol is in question

Tags: swift, class, properties, protocols, mutability

I was trying to implement a Networking Module for my personal project and I was following TDD. When I am writing the test cases I came across a compile error and I was not able to map the error with Swift concepts. I could have easily ignored it and done the implementation in a different way. But I was not feeling right to do it as I want to know the exact reason to the error.

This is the code snippet.

```
import UIKit

protocol HTTPClient {
    var url: String? {get set}
    func load()
}

class HTTPClientSpy: HTTPClient {
    var url: String?
    
    func load() {
        
    }
}

class Feed {
    let client: HTTPClient

    init(client: HTTPClient) {
        self.client = client
    }

    func loadFeed() {
        client.url = "" //Compile Error -> Cannot assign to property: 'client' is a 'let' constant
        client.load()
    }
}
```

When I do the following change the error goes away

```
class Feed {
    let client: HTTPClientSpy

    init(client: HTTPClientSpy) {
        self.client = client
    }

    func loadFeed() {
        client.url = "" //No compile errors
        client.load()
    }
}
```

Swift classes are mutable. which means we should be able to change the properties of the instance even if we create a constant reference to the instance. It seems there is something to do with the protocol conformance in this case which I cannot understand.

Can someone please explain the theory behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swift classes are mutable. which means we should be able to change the properties of the instance even if we create a constant reference to the instance.

Indeed you are right. But *structs* can conform to your `HTTPClient` protocol too:

```
struct SomeStruct: HTTPClient {
    var url: String?
    func load() {}
}
```

If `Feed` were passed an instance of `SomeStruct`, then `client.url = ""` would not work. Normally you cannot change the `var`s of a struct-typed variable, if you declared the variable with `let`.

```
let client = SomeStruct()
client.url = "" // error
```

The compiler doesn't know whether `client` in `Feed` is storing a struct or a class, so it tries to be safe and doesn't let you change `url`.

You can make sure that only classes can conform to the protocol by adding `: AnyObject`:

```
protocol HTTPClient: AnyObject {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow.. Super Awesome. Got it straight away. Thank you @Sweeper